# Power Apps/Sharepoint, Item will not change after modification

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

Trying to get my makeshift vlookup to connect my two lists. The idea is when a user modifies a record it will reflect from List Template to list population.

The "vlookup" is based on EmployeeLoginID (template) Employee_PrimaryLoginID(population).
The columns supposed to be updated are "Submitted", "Yes/Idk" and "No".

This works when I create a record from scratch but not for modification.

Can anyone help with this?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Condition one: Vlookup(if employeeloginid exists in template) and fill in "Submitted" in population.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Condition two: Vlookup(if employeeloginid exists in template) and fill in "Yes/Idk","no" in population if those fields are chosen as Yes/Idk , No in population.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi Jonnyboi. Can you tell me which columns are in these two lists? According to your screenshots, there are "CPDE-02..", "CPDE-056.." and "CPDE-05..." in the Condition2. Do you want to fill in "yes/Idk" when any of these three column is yes?

Comment: Hi Echo. The 3 CPDE questions, If all are "Yes" or "I Don't Know" in template list I want to fill in "Yes/Idk" in population list. If they are all "No" in template list I want to fill in "No" in population list.   An additional logic that I didn't think I incorporated is, if any of the 3 questions are Yes or Idk in template, then Fill in Yes/Idk in population. Meaning all 3 have to be answered "No" in template for it to be populated "No" in population.  Hopefully this makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please following steps:**

1.List A:

[image]

2.List B:

[image]

3.Create Microsoft Flow

**Note:** Because as long as you modify item, the "**When an item is created or modified**" will be triggered. So I set the Trigger Condition, and the "**When an item is created or modified**" will only be triggered if the **Status** is **Approved**

[image]

4.Save and Test Flow

======================= **Updated Answer** =========================

Yes, you don’t need to add this Trigger Condition

**My Flow:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey, why did you put the trigger action in? What does this do? The screenshot is kind of cut off.
Also I notice you didnt include "I Don't Know" in your conditions. Going to play around with your suggestions.

Comment: Hi Jonnyboi. I have updated answer under initial My Answer. Hope this can help you to solve issue. Have a nice day!